# Is there an Open/Libre Office fork that supports dynamic loading ("Declare") in VBA on Linux?

Tags: vba, openoffice, libreoffice

The versions of Open Office I have can't use "Declare" in VBA on Linux. They just tell me that the feature is not implemented. ("Declare" is used for dynamic loading of dylib or dll libraries, which are like .so libraries).

I'm finding it hard to search for this information, because (1) Most of the information is about Excel, and (2) Most of the information about Open Office only supporting "Declare" on Windows is very old.

Comment: The Python [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module can work with .so libraries from an OpenOffice macro.  Is that an acceptable answer?  If not, there are several ways that it can be done from Basic, but they are somewhat buggy and may not handle your particular library.  Note: The language that OpenOffice uses is called Basic, not VBA which is for Microsoft only.

Comment: @JimK "No" is an answer, I'd accept that. Open Office Basic is not the same as VBA, but some forks have a VBA compatible language: I'm not sure what it is called, but it's not the old OO Basic (the OOB object model was not the same, so it couldn't run imported VBA modules which reference the container). I can use flaky work-arounds, but I'll ask a separate question if I get to that.